# Why casting to unrelated interface produce ClassCastException instead of compile time exception?

Tags: java, casting

Why in this snippet while Tree interface is not related to Bug class it does not produce compile time exception?

```
interface Tree {}
class Bug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug bug = new Bug();
        Tree tree = (Tree) bug;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark `Bug` as `final` and you will get your compiler error as expected.

This is because `Bug` *could* have a subclass that *does* implement `Tree`. If `bug` actually stores a reference to an instance of that subclass, then the cast will succeed. Since there is a chance that the cast can succeed, the compiler doesn't stop you from casting.

In most cases, you can cast from any non-final class to any interface. According to the JLS [§5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1), when you try to cast a variable of reference type `S` to interface `T`:

> If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (**because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might**).

Comment: I see that when I reverse it and Tree is a class and Bug is interface it still works the same way. Code compiles but it throw ClassCastException at runtime.
`class Tree {}
interface Bug {}
class Ant implements Bug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug bug = new Ant();
        Tree tree = (Tree) bug;
    }
}`
So if I understand it correctly if at least one of the types is interface and none of the types is final class then casting will compile (?).

Comment: @bridgemnc Yes, in general, any interface can be casted to any non-final class too. The same argument applies. Quoting the JLS here, "because even if T does not implement S, a subclass of T might" (`T` is the class `Tree`, `S` is the interface `Bug`).